# Two versions of the same function behave differently in stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I would like to plot a function using the following data:

```
my_data <- data.frame("x" = rep(1:4, times = 20))
my_coef <- c(78, -71, 43, -7)
```

There are two different ways to write the function:

```
fun_version1 <- function(x) {
    my_coef[1] + my_coef[2]*x + my_coef[3]*(x^2) + my_coef[4]*(x^3)
}


fun_version2 <- function(x){
    sum(as.vector(outer(x, 0:3, FUN="^")) * my_coef)
}
```

Although both functions return exactly the same results when plugging in values, only fun_version1 looks fine in the ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)    
# plot using version 1 of the function
        ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = x)) + 
            stat_function(fun = fun_version1, aes(col = "1"), lwd = 1.2)

# plot using version 2 of the function
        ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = x)) + 
            stat_function(fun = fun_version2, aes(col = "1"), lwd = 1.2)
```

I need to plot functions in the form of **fun_version2**. Is there a way to use this version in the ggplot function `stat_function()` or some kind of workaround?

Comment: The `sum()` breaks the vectorization. You can "re-vectorize" with `fun_version2 <- Vectorize(fun_version2)`.

Comment: Great, that fixed it! Thanks!